# how to solve the error `expand_string': undefined method `reject' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in rubber when deploying in Amazon EC2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rubber

I am using "rubber" to deploy my project in "Amazon EC2". I am following the railscasts episode [#347 Rubber and Amazon EC2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/347-rubber-and-amazon-ec2?autoplay=true). But when I am trying this command

```
$cap rubber:create_staging
```

It is asking for

Hostname to use for staging instance [production]:

Now When I entered it gives an error

```
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rubber-2.0.1/lib/rubber/environment.rb:137:in `expand_string': undefined method `reject' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

How can i solve this problem? Please share with me if any one have any idea.

Code detail:

```
[ec2-user@ip blog]$ cap rubber:create_staging
    triggering load callbacks
  * 2015-06-05 09:52:42 executing `rubber:init'
  * 2015-06-05 09:52:43 executing `rubber:create_staging'
Hostname to use for staging instance [production]:
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rubber-2.0.1/lib/rubber/environment.rb:137:in `expand_string': undefined method `reject' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rubber-2.0.1/lib/rubber/environment.rb:137:in `eval'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rubber-2.0.1/lib/rubber/environment.rb:137:in `expand_string'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rubber-2.0.1/lib/rubber/environment.rb:149:in `expand'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rubber-2.0.1/lib/rubber/environment.rb:115:in `[]'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rubber-2.0.1/lib/rubber/environment.rb:193:in `method_missing'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rubber-2.0.1/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/utils.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `invoke_task_directly'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:101:in `find_and_execute_task'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:46:in `block in execute_requested_actions'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:45:in `each'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:45:in `execute_requested_actions'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/help.rb:19:in `execute_requested_actions_with_help'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:34:in `execute!'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/bin/cap:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/cap:23:in `load'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a version of the gem from 2012?  Does it work if you use the latest version?

Comment: No, I am just following the tutorial. What should I , what you suggest?

Comment: Well I'd assume that the latest version will probably be fuller featured and fix old bugs.  With it looking like the issue is in rubber you can either try a newer version or fix the code in rubber yourself.  I'd doubt the maintainers would fix a bug in a version that's 3 years old unless it happened in much newer versions.  You can always ask though I guess - just create an issue on the github repo for rubber